# Etymological relatives of English "put" and "get" in standard and dialect German

Tags: etymology

The English verbs *put* and *get* have a long etymological history and several close etymological relatives amongst the Germanic languages. But correspondences to standard German seem to be completely absent (according to Wiktionary).

Do you know any siblings in standard or dialect German?

Comment: [This entry on „vergessen“](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV01423) may be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Both *"to put"*, and *"to get"* do indeed seem to have old Germanic roots from their etymology.

> **to put**
>   ...probably from a Germanic stem that also produced Danish putte "to put," Swedish dialectal putta; Middle Dutch pote "scion, plant," Dutch poten "to plant," Old Norse pota "to poke." <sup>[Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=put&allowed_in_frame=0)</sup>
>
> **to get**
>   ...from Proto-Germanic *getan* [...]. Old English, as well as Dutch and Frisian, had the root only in compounds (e.g. begietan "to beget," see beget; forgietan "to forget," see forget) [...] <sup>[Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=get&allowed_in_frame=0)</sup>

In contemporary German not much of the Germanic roots is preserved. However there are some remnants, at least in dialects from the northern regions, or in compounds.

Here are some examples I found:

> **paten/poten:**  (*to plant*)
>   *verb.* pflänzlinge setzen: "als ob er nichts weiter gethan hätte als weiden paten". Bode Montaigne 3, 70. ein *nd.* wort, abgeleitet von *mnd.* pate, pote, potte, nd. pate, setzling, pôte, pfropfreis [...] <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GP01257)</sup>
>
> **vergessen:**  (*to forget*)
>   Es handelt sich um präfigierte Verben zu einem Simplex, das in ahd. geʒʒan ‘erlangen’ (8. Jh.), anord. geta ‘schaffen, erreichen, erzeugen, lernen, nennen, vermuten’ (woraus mengl. geten, engl. to get ‘erhalten, bekommen’) <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=vergessen&submit_button=Suche&view=1)</sup>

Comment: I wonder if you think SCHTUPPEN is related to put?

Comment: @MartyGreen: *schtuppen* is more likely to be related to *stopfen*, *stupfen* - both have a common root with the English "to stop".